# Regex to extract word inside round brackets

Tags: regex

I have been stuck with this regex issue for a long time now.
I have the following string.

```
[{"op": "replace", "path": "/endDate", "value": "#{$PurchaseOrderExtensions.findOne(_extid).getEndDate().toString()}"}]
```

I am totally confused how to extract the word `_extid` which is within the round brackets. The confusing part is that there are many round brackets. I need to extract only the one after the occurrence of `findOne`.

I tried the following regular expressions but none of them even matched the string to extract the one after `findOne`.

```
/\{(\(\w+\))\}/?
/\\((\\w+)\\)/?
and many more...
```

What mistake am I doing here?

Comment: Input looks like a JSON, why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: *"What mistake am I doing here?"* you're not using a JSON parser is one thing.  The fact you have code inside of your string is another bad thing; likely to be `eval`d later or some kind of dynamic execution.

Comment: are you saying the extid is the data, which may change? you want to get to findOne(whaterver is here) ?

Comment: @ash I know how to use JSON parsing. But I am using Xtend, which does not support any JSON parsing like we use in basic Java. In fact, it does not allow to add any extra java jars. And I do not think "not using JSON parser" is a mistake. It is a choice. Plus I have put in this code in this string with some purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just find for *findOne* in your regex:

```
findOne\((\w+)\)
```

Then you can get your string from the inner capture group.

Answer (score 1):

```
'(?<=findOne)\(.*?\)'
```

Example

```
grep -Po '(?<=findOne)\(.*?\)' file
```

or

```
grep -Po 'findOne\K\(.*?\)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you just include `findOne` into your expression?

Like:

`/\.findOne\((.*?)\)/`

depending on the language and use, you may need to double the backslashes, or as mentioned - just use JSON parser

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this that captures what is inside round brackets:

```
\([a-z1-9_]*\)
```